# Hierarchy of namespaces, headers and objects

Tags: c++

From what I understand, the namespace std contains all of C++ standard libraries, and one of the standard libraries is the iostream and it has the objects cout and cin.

```
std namespace 
       |
   iostream
       |
   cout, cin
```

Is the above structure correct? Or is it different?

Comment: `iostream` is a header (a file). `std` is a `namespace`, `cout` and `cin` are objects within the `std` namespace.

Comment: cout and cin are not functions, they are objects

Comment: @ryan iostream is also a type in the standard library -  it's a typedef for `basic_iostream<char>`

Comment: This is a starting point: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Answer (score 1):

> From what I understand, the namespace std contains all of C++ standard
>   libraries, and one of the standard libraries is the iostream and it
>   has the functions cout and cin.

Not quite.

- Although almost all of the standard library is in namespace `std`, we also have the C components outside of `std` when using the old header form (`<stdio.h>` instead of `<cstdio>`), and the `assert` macro, which is not scoped.
- `std::cin` and `std::cout` are not functions but objects.
- `<iostream>` is just the name of a header which contains *parts* of what the C++ ISO standard officially names "Input/output library" (`std::iostream` is a rarely used `typedef` for the `std::basic_iostream<char>` class).
- Certain components of the library can be pulled in by different `#include`s. For example, `std::initializer_list` becomes available through `<initializer_list>` or through includes like `<vector>`.

Without going into too much detail, header files and scoping are two **orthogonal** concepts in C++. In other words, they exist in parallel to each other. There is no useful hierarchy among/between them.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct when you assume that  everything that's in the standard library is contained in the `std` namespace, *with a few exceptions*, as per 17.6.1.1/§3 in the standard:

> All library entities except macros, **operator new** and **operator delete** are defined within the namespace **std** or namespaces nested within namespace **std**. It is unspecified whether names declared in a specific namespace are declared directly in that namespace or in an inline namespace inside that namespace.

Then, when you say "the libraries", there's only one library here, the "standard library". `iostream` is a header of this library. But that doesn't mean everything from a header is in a specific namespace.

For example, `cin` and `cout` are directly in the `std` namespace, but are included with the `<iostream>` header.

Comment: It should be noted that the standard itself is inconsistent regarding the pluralisation. In §17.1, it talks about "the contents of the C++ standard library" and "the components in the library". But the section headings say, for example, "String library", not "String library component".